# Manage multiple tables relationed in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model

So, i have three tables

Table: **Users**

```
 _________________
|  id    |  user  |
-------------------
|   1    |  Roy   |
|   2    |  Ben   |
|________|________|
```

Table: **Hability_lists** // Where i set the list with all habilities available

```
 ___________________________________
|  id    |  category  | subcategory | 
------------------------------------
|   1    | Programmer |     PHP     |
|   2    | Programmer |     ASP     |
|________|____________|_____________|
```

Table: **Habilities** // Where i set the habilities from all users

```
 ________________________________________
|  id    |  user_id   | hability_list_id | 
-----------------------------------------
|   1    |     2      |         1        |
|   2    |     1      |         2        |
|________|____________|__________________|
```

By this, we can see that:

**Roy** are a **ASP Programmer** and **Ben** are a **PHP Programmer**

But, how to set relative models like this using CakePHP?
I know how by using two models but not using three models.

There is some way to do this? Or maybe a better way to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Alexandre, please could you post your model code so we can see your current associations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with an MVC framework it's highly recommended to follow [its conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). So a few changes may be beneficial for you.

What you are looking for its the HABTM (Has And Belongs To Many) association between the "users" table and the "habilities" table *. I'm guessing, by the design of your table, that a user can have multiple habilities, otherwise you should check the hasMany association.

It should be something like this:

Table habilities:
    select * from habilities;

```
+----+------------+----------------------+----------+
| id | category   | subcategoy | created | modified |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | Programmer | ASP        |         |          |
|  2 | Programmer | PHP        |         |          |
|  3 | Musician   | Classical  |         |          |
+----+------------+------------+---------+----------+
```

Table users:
    select * from users;

```
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name  | created             | modified            | **
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Roy   | 2012-08-15 02:52:18 | 2013-01-17 03:25:28 |
|  2 | Ben   | 2012-11-10 03:36:12 | 2012-11-10 03:36:12 |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Relational table for HABTM:
    select * from habilities_users;

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| id | hability_id | user_id | created | modified |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+
|  1 | 1           | 2       |         |          |
|  2 | 2           | 1       |         |          |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Look the reference columns in habilities_users, they're singular with a _id suffix to work with CakePHP.

Defining the models classes it's also important, since it's where you define all their associations.

app/Model/User.php

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Hability');
}
```

app/Model/Hability.php

```
<?php
class Hability extends AppModel {
  public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');
}
```

The table habilities_users doesn't need a model file, its behaviours and properties are implicit in the declaration of its associated models.

* using those names it's also the CakePHP way. [[link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html)]

** adding "created" and "modified" in each table will store those events for each record automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [HasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm).

This allows you to have two models - `User` and `Hability` that are joined by a "tweener" table.